# PLSQL - Table of associative array keys or values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an associative array of integers indexed by integers and I would like to be able to use it in a where clause of a select. Something like:

```
TYPE myAssocArray IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER NOT NULL INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable_Column IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(myAssocArray.keys))
```

and same thing for values.
As far as I have understood, this is not directly possible as an associative array is not an SQL type. Is there a proper way to hack around this limitation?
Thanks in advance for all the suggestions!

Comment: What version of Oracle?  If you are using 12.1, you can pass a local variable of your associative array type to the `table` function (though you can't call a function that returns the associative array type from the `table` function).  But if that's what you're doing with the collection, it seems unlikely that you need an associative array-- you can define a nested table collection in SQL and use that instead.

Comment: My Oracle version is 12.1.3. Could you elaborate a little on your suggestion? If I simpy pass the associative array to the <code> table </code> function I will get an ORA-22905. By the way, associative arrays are required in other parts of the code so I cannot replace them with nested tables.

Comment: http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2015/04/table-functions-introduction-and.html includes a decent overview of the options available in 12.1 to mix PL/SQL types with the `table` function.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, I will take some time to browse through it!

Answer (score 0):

Create sql level nested table collection . And copy keys from  AssocArray to the collection.

```
create type l_number is table of number;


declare
   TYPE myAssocArray IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER NOT NULL INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   arr myAssocArray;
   vKey PLS_INTEGER; 
   keys_list l_number := l_number();
begin
  arr(1) := 1;
  arr(5) := 1;
  arr(6) := 1;

  vKey := arr.first();

  while vKey is not null loop
    keys_list.extend(1);
    keys_list(keys_list.count) := vKey;
    vKey := arr.next(vKey);
  end loop;

  for rec in ( select column_value from table(keys_list)) loop
   dbms_output.put_line(rec.column_value);
  end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had thought of this option, but I was hoping there was a solution that did not require to duplicate all the values. If there is not, I will accept this as the answer.